# How to make a material for a candy cane?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor

So far, I've got a red and white Wave Texture, wich is mixed (Fac: 0.200) with a Glossy BSDF (Roughness: 0.020). 
I also added an Image Texture (Scratches) for Displacement connected with Multiply (Value: 0.050).
However, I'm not completely satisfied with the material. Could someone give me any advice?

This is, how my material looks like:
[image: recent material]
And this is how I would like it to look:
[image: candy cane]

Sorry for my (probably) bad English, I'm Austrian.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The biggest difference between your render and the picture is that the picture has a ton of things (esp. lights) to reflect all around, while yours has only one lamp and its specular highlight. Add an HDR image to the background and your render will look lightyears better.

See tip 3 here for examples:

http://www.blenderguru.com/articles/making-better-materials/

See this site for some free, quality HDRs:

https://hdrihaven.com

---

One other thing is that in the picture there is a little gap between the red and white whereas yours cuts cleanly. Perhaps add an extremely thin black line there, or use the striping as a bumpmap.